# MATLAB and using mod

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB. Assuming x takes values of 1:100.

I want to do the following

```
for x=1  do procedure
for x=2  do procedure
for x=3  do procedure
for x=4  dont do procedure
for x=5  dont do procedure 
for x=6  do procedure
for x=7  do procedure
for x=8  do procedure
for x=9  dont do procedure
for x=10 dont do procedure
for x=11 do procedure
for x=12  do procedure
for x=13  do  procedure
for x=14  dont procedure
for x=15  dont procedure
```

The pattern is for 3 consecutive x's we do something while for the next two we dont.

I used a

```
 if mod(x,5)~=0
```

it takes care of the x=5, 10, 15..

But i have no idea to take care of the ones at x=4, 14, 19.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `ismember`, e.g.,

```
~ismember(mod(x,5),[0,4])
```

**Example**

```
>> ~ismember(mod(1:10,5),[0,4])
ans =

  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
```